# Javascript - How can I check to see if a url is loosely equal to the one in the location bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`function isSameUrl(url){ /*what goes here?*/ }`

If the current url is `http://www.example.com/test#bar`, the following would return true:

```
 isSameUrl('#bar')
 isSameUrl('/test#bar')
 isSameUrl('http://www.example.com/test#bar')
```

Basically, if the location bar would not change if a link with the specified url was clicked, then it should return true.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `www.example.com/test#bar` is composed of the relative path `www.example.com/test` and the fragment `bar`; resolved from `http://www.example.com/test#bar` it will result in `http://www.example.com/www.example.com/test#bar`.

Comment: @gumbo - you're right, I'll take that one out of the examples.

Comment: how about `new RegExp(url).test(document.location)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the URI reference before comparing it. You can use [this regular expression to parse URI references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) (slightly modified):

```
/^([^:\/?#]+:)?(?:\/\/([^\/?#]+))?([^?#]+)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?/
```

Then you can compare each component that is not `undefined` to the corresponding component in the `location` object:

```
function isSameUrl(url, location) {
    location = location || document.location;
    var match = url.match(/^([^:\/?#]+:)?(?:\/\/([^\/?#]+))?([^?#]+)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?/);
    if (typeof match[1] === "string" && match[1].length > 0 && match[1].toLowerCase() !== location.protocol) return false;
    if (typeof match[2] === "string" && match[2].length > 0 && match[2].replace(new RegExp(":("+{"http:":80,"https:":443}[location.protocol]+")?$"),"") !== location.host) return false;
    if (typeof match[3] === "string" && match[3].length > 0 && match[3] !== location.pathname) return false;
    if (typeof match[4] === "string" && match[4].length > 0 && match[4] !== location.search) return false;
    if (typeof match[5] === "string" && match[5].length > 0 && match[5] !== location.hash) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an exact match

```
var isSameUrl = function(url) {
    return window.location.href == url;
}
```

and for your needs

changed for query string support

```
var isSameUrl = function(url) {
  var path = function(s) { return s.replace(/\?.*$/,''); };
  return path(window.location.href) == url ||
         path(window.location.pathname + window.location.hash) == url ||
         window.location.hash == url;
}
```

Comment: wrongly returns true if url is `/test` and current location is `http://www.example.com/subfolder/test`

Comment: @James Thanks, I'll test it out for a bit and see if there are any edge cases it misses.

Comment: do you want to match query parameters or ignore them in the match?

Comment: Basically I want to return true whenever the location bar would not change if a link with the url was clicked.

Comment: I see, changed to strip the query string, this is assuming that none of your links have a query string if so could you add them to the question

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, the value of the location bar is stored in a Location object which you can access using the `window.location` property. It has various conveniences for accessing various parts of the URL, but the portion of the URL after the domain name can be found in: `window.location.pathname`.  The portion after `#` can be found in `window.location.hash` (but only in the most recent browsers). The portion after `?` can be found in `window.location.search` -- and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a string is included in  your URL, you can use this:

```
function isSameUrl(test) {
    return window.location.href.indexOf(test) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think isSame (url) would be something like this:

```
function isSame(url){
    return window.location.indexOf(url) > 0
}
```

Comment: not if url is `/test` and the current url is `www.example.com/subfolder/test`. It would wrongly return true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a **regular expression** based off 'url' parameter of your function, then test the current url against that regular expression.  See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp for the details on creating the regular expression and on using the test() method to check for matches.  There are many good regular expression testers online as well.

Comment: W3Schools?  Your points make sense--use some other resource for the details of a regular expression then.  But use a regular expression to solve this problem--that is the answer to this question.

Comment: do you know of a regular expression that would work for this?